# Cover letters written along with research paper submission

Tags: data-request, research

I am looking for a dataset containing cover letters written along with research paper submission ([example](http://jamia.oxfordjournals.org/for_authors/index.html)). Ideally, with paper admission notification, and DOI of paper if published.